# Updating Flutter page after setState()

Tags: if-statement, widget, dart, state, flutter

I have a user follow/unfollow page that searches Firebase for a list of followers and returns a Boolean if their usedID is found...

```
Future<Null> _friends() async {
    fb.child("users/${userid}/Following/${id}").onValue.listen((Event event) {

        setState((){
          if (event.snapshot.value != null) {
            friends == true;
          } else if (event.snapshot.value == null) {
            friends == false;
          }
        });
    });
  }
```

The bool is then set in a separate function that changes a public bool...

```
bool friends;
```

The trouble is that my Widget/Scaffold doesn't update here...

```
friends == true ? new RaisedButton(onPressed: unfollow()) :
                  new RaisedButton(onPressed: follow());
```

Any ideas? I'll update with exact code once later.

Comment: There is no way of telling unless you show how you are checking Firebase data

Comment: @aziza Please review added code

Comment: try not to make if statement inside setState, instead have two setState, one inside if and one inside else and both set the friends value accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

the issue is that you've used an `==` (equality) comparison operator instead of `=` (assignment). Change your code to the following:

```
  Future<Null> _friends() async {
     fb.child("users/${userid}/Following/${id}").onValue.listen((Event event) {
      setState((){
        // this will return true or false which is what you want based on your code :)
        friends = event.snapshot.value == null; 
      });
  });
}
```